# pass data to form in many Django CreateViews

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have several models which share an attribute, `course_offering`.  On my site, the relevant value of the attribute is generally determined by keyword arguments from the url.  So, in many subclasses of CreateView, I would like automatically to pass the relevant value to the form.

For any particular model class, [this post](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/django-class-based-views-action-forms-handling/) offers an approach: override `get_form_kwargs()`  to set an initial object.  For example in the present case,

```
class OfferingMixin(Object):
    def get_course_offering(self,**kwargs):
        offering_slug = self.kwargs['offering_slug']
        course_offering = CourseOffering.objects.get(
            slug=offering_slug)
        return course_offering

class CreateSyllabusView(OfferingMixin,CreateView):
    model=Syllabus
    def get_form_kwargs(self,**kwargs):
        course_offering=self.get_course_offering(**kwargs)
        instance = Syllabus(course_offering=course_offering)
        kwargs.update({'instance':instance})
        return kwargs
```

But, this applies to a fixed model class, and I would like to handle many model classes while avoiding unnecessary duplication of code.  For example, would it be possible somehow to subclass CreateView to, say, OfferingCreateView, and then subclass OfferingCreateView to CreateSyllabusView?  If so, I'm not sure how to do it!  Of course, it could be that this idea is totally misguided, in which case it would be nice to learn a good approach.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: unless I'm missing something, can you not just call super on `get_form_kwargs` inside your overriden `CreateView` and then reference the model via `self.object`? (or `self.model`?)

Comment: `self.model.objects.create` is what I was referring to, you might need to set some breakpoints to check what values are around

Comment: thank you.  yes, it worked to put `model=self.model`
    and then `instance=model.objects.create(course_offering=course_offering)`